# Multiple IN statements for WHERE. Would this return good data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT ['VISA CK  - 021810$'].[ACCT NBR     #1], ['VISA CK  - 021810$'].[ALT CUST NM  #1], ['VISA CK  - 021810$'].[LAST USED]
FROM ['VISA CK  - 021810$']
WHERE ['VISA CK  - 021810$'].[ALT CUST NM  #1] 
    IN (
        SELECT ['VISA CK  - 021810$'].[ALT CUST NM  #1]
        FROM ['VISA CK  - 021810$']
        GROUP BY ['VISA CK  - 021810$'].[ALT CUST NM  #1]
            HAVING COUNT(['VISA CK  - 021810$'].[ALT CUST NM  #1]) > 1
        )
    AND ['VISA CK  - 021810$'].[ACCT NBR     #1]
    IN (
        SELECT ['VISA CK  - 021810$'].[ACCT NBR     #1]
        FROM ['VISA CK  - 021810$']
        GROUP BY ['VISA CK  - 021810$'].[ACCT NBR     #1]
            HAVING COUNT(['VISA CK  - 021810$'].[ACCT NBR     #1]) > 1
        )
```

Comment: Column names like that should be illegal :)

Comment: Seems like it would, though I agree with Nick that it sure is painful to read.  When you tried it what happened?

Comment: AGREED!! The results of importing an .csv from another application...

Comment: I get results, and most seem like the results I'm looking for, but there are a few rows selected that don't seem like they belong.

Comment: @Nick Craver: yeah. Thank god at least the table names are sensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewritten using JOINs:

```
SELECT t.[ACCT NBR     #1], 
       t.[ALT CUST NM  #1], 
       t.[LAST USED]
  FROM ['VISA CK  - 021810$'] t
  JOIN (SELECT ['VISA CK  - 021810$'].[ALT CUST NM  #1]
          FROM ['VISA CK  - 021810$']
      GROUP BY ['VISA CK  - 021810$'].[ALT CUST NM  #1]
        HAVING COUNT(['VISA CK  - 021810$'].[ALT CUST NM  #1]) > 1) x ON x.[ALT CUST NM  #1] =   t.[ALT CUST NM  #1] 
  JOIN (SELECT ['VISA CK  - 021810$'].[ACCT NBR     #1]
          FROM ['VISA CK  - 021810$']
      GROUP BY ['VISA CK  - 021810$'].[ACCT NBR     #1]
        HAVING COUNT(['VISA CK  - 021810$'].[ACCT NBR     #1]) > 1) y ON y.[ACCT NBR     #1] = t.[ACCT NBR     #1]
```

Make sure it returns the data you expect - tune after that.  Assuming the query you provided is correct, JOINs are generally preferred over subqueries but reviewing and comparing the Execution Plan will tell you what is best for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

It is a valid SQL construct but we can't comment on whether it works or not.

You are saying: for each row in `['VISA CK  - 021810$']`, return this row if I find matches for both `[ACCT NBR     #1]` and `[ALT CUST NM  #1]` in their relative IN clauses

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would return good data. The WHERE clause will assure that both IN clauses are respected before returning any data as you're using an AND.

Comment: This is the first time I've used multiple IN's with AND. Thank you for clarifying.